# Why does this DataTrigger not work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Yes, the datatrigger is inside a style.  Now that that issue is behind us, I'm interested to know why the following code is nonfunctional.
I should see a blue background for the data grid but the style is ignored.  What am I doing wrong?  Note I've named the Window element "root".

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTriggerTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="root">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}" >
        <DataGrid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=SomeCondition}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=SomeCondtion}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Style>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Data"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool SomeCondition { get; set; }
    public List<string> SomeData { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        SomeData = new List<string> { "hello", "world" };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues.  The first is that you need to either implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the PropertyChanged event on the SomeCondition setter property, or make SomeCondition a DependencyProperty.  Without doing that, your UI will never know that the property value has changed.

The second is that I believe that datatriggers won't occur if the value is the same as the default value.  So, the false trigger will never occur because the boolean default is false.  I think that it's expected that you will set the default style values to match the default value of the property.. false in this case... like this:

```
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="Blue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=SomeCondition}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

The default is blue when the property is false, and changes when the property is true.

Finally, you should use an ObservableCollection instead of a List for SomeData.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes you are correct I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and in my application I do.  However my question is "why is the style being ignored?" not "why does the color not change when the condition changes".  As you point out the default is blue and changes when the property is true.  However that is not what I see.  I see grey which indicates something is wrong with the style.  Also, the grid is able to bind to the list.  At the moment I'm not interested in updating when data changes.

Comment: The problem - as usual - is me. I had a typeo SomeCondtion is wrong. mdm20 thank you for at least giving me a shove in the right direction.  The code I posted will work if the magic strings are spelled correctly.

Comment: I didn't notice that typo either :)

Answer (score 2):

XAML Booleans are Case-Insensitive, however, I believe you need to use "False" and "True" when using it in the Value property.